# Does the Intel RDTSC instruction (or equivalent) count clocks only in your task, or globally?

Tags: assembly, intel, benchmarking

Related to earlier question: [making mistake in inline assembler in gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473452/making-mistake-in-inline-assembler-in-gcc)

in the RDTSC or similar instruction, is the count only for your process, or is it a global count?  If there is a context switch, is the only inaccuracy the cost of the context switch itself, or is the entire time the CPU is on a different job counted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The count is for the whole system (including your running process and every other process).
The instruction counts the number of ticks occurred from reset.

Comment: so is there any standard library to catch the context switch and save the clock number in and out?

Comment: You'd have to modify the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

It counts instructions per core(hence why you shouldn't use it for timing on a multicore system). The intel developer guides should be your first stop when a query arises.

Comment: Actually on newer CPUs it is synchronized.  There's a CPUID bit that tells you (you can find the details in the Linux implementation of the VDSO for gettimeofday).

Comment: True, however, if the cpu doesn't, your sol, which is why you should stick with higher level api's, like microsofts performance counter